# Backup.ab - Java NumberFormatException Error

Tags: adb, backup, data-recovery, java

I got an `ab` file with adb from my phone's notes folder.  Which I can not access without root. I am trying to convert it to the tar file but `cmd` gives me this error in the picture.
My command was ;

```
Java -jar abe.jar unpack MyFile.ab MyFile.tar password
```

And I'm trying to use this with Android Backup Extractor Master with Gradle. Can you help me please I'm trying to save this file for over 100 days.

[image]

Comment: Hi Kaan, it is much easier to read if you post teh text of teh error instead of a screenshot.

Comment: How large is the `MyFile.ab` file` If it is less than 1Kb then it is most likely invalid.

Comment: The file name suffix `.ab` is no guarantee of this type of backup file format. Please show the hexadecimal header of the file.

Comment: Invalid format. Compression header not found: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor/blob/master-20221109063121-8fdfc5e/src/org/nick/abe/AndroidBackup.java#L79

Comment: @RohitGupta i tried but i couldnt do it sorry

Comment: @Robert it is like 7Kb

Comment: @alecxs it is ab file i got it from phone with adb but before i tried to make it tar, i open it with text document so it became a txt file and i converted it to the ab file again maybe file corrupted in here

Comment: @IrfanLatif i didnt understand what should i do

Comment: @Robert By the way i got this file from folders that i can not reach without root. Maybe it corrupted because i turned it txt and make it ab again. Because of that i'm trying to get ab file again but i just got 1kb file how can i fix that

Comment: On devices running Android 12+ adb backup is limited to old apps. Recently apps that are compiled to be executed on Android 12+ don't return any data when executing `adb backup`. The only workaround is downgrading the app to an old version.

Comment: Well my goal was the get files from my note app folder. I found information that deleted  notes are stored in /data/data/com.miui.notes in my Xiaomi phone. I mistakenly deleted my notes few months ago so i'm trying to reach my deleted notes from that folder . So you think if i downgrad notes application (which is a system app) i can reach that files with adb backup?

Comment: First the app has to support backup at all, second downgrading only makes sense if you can go back to a version that was designed for an Android version prior to 12 (which is unlikely for a system app). Third, if you want to perform data recovery you have to do it immediately not several months later.